# How do I handle Kafka Consumer Deserialization errors for records serialized with the KafkaAvroSerializer?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kafka-consumer-api

I am working on the implementation for a Kafka Consumer that consumes messages that are serialized by the KafkaAvroSerializer.  I am encountering the following error when we are trying to deserialize Kafka Records for which we do not have corresponding avro schema:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Could not find class com.appdynamics.avro.cn.collectors.models.v1.CollectionStatusEventDto specified in writer's schema whilst finding reader's schema for a SpecificRecord.
```

I am looking for a way either (1) handle this exception gracefully and seek past the invalid record or (2) deserialize the record without the corresponding Avro schema.  I have seen approaches where people will use the byte array deserializer, but in my implementation of that, I was getting errors related to "missing magic bytes" because the Kafka Records were being serialized with the KafkaAvroSerializer.  I have also seen implementations that handle errors using the ErrorHandlingDeserializer2.class, except we are not using the DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory class, rather we are using a simple KafkaConsumer.   Any advice as to how I would go about fixing this error would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: To investigate this further, can you make a small reproducer at github ?